# Use Click Image to Play Youtube Video in a Wordpress Loop

Tags: posts, loop, jquery, youtube

Here is my code on Playing Youtube Video when an image is clicked..

The HTML

```
    <div id="my-video" style="display:none;">
    <div class="responsive-video">
    <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/kCfP003Btjw?rel=0&hd=1&autoplay=1" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-img">
    <img src="http://yalleshleiron.com/ds/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/HP.jpg" class="featimg attachment-full wp-post-image" alt="HP">
<a class="video-play-button" href="#" id="imageID"></a>
```

The jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function( $ ) {   
$(document).ready( function( ) {                
$('#imageID').click(function() {
$('#my-video').show();
$('#imageID').hide();
$('.featimg').hide();
});

});
})(jQuery);      
</script>
```

I tried to used it in a loop, but if i clicked on one image, it plays all the video's inside the loop.

Here is the code

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('clearfix'); ?> role="article">
    <header>
    <div class="feature-img">
    <?php
    if(get_field('youtube_id'))
    { ?>
    <div id="my-video" style="display:none;">
        <div class="responsive-video">
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo get_field('youtube_id'); ?>?rel=0&hd=1&autoplay=1" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
        </div>
        </div>
     <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'featimg')); ?><a class="video-play-button" href="#" id="imageID"></a>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'featimg')); ?>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
       <div class="gallery-header">
            <h3 class="single-title" itemprop="headline"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        </div>
    </header> <!-- end article header -->
    <section class="post_content clearfix" itemprop="articleBody">
    <?php the_content(); ?>                             
    </section> <!-- end article section -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>  
</article>
```

I want it be dynamic, but I don't know how. Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
<div id="my-video" style="display:none;">
```

as you can see, id is static and is the same for all posts. First of all this is not compliant with html standard: tag id must be unique.

As a side effect if you use the id selector in jquery and the id is used a lot of times jquery apply function a lot of times...

So first you have to make id unique, in the loop use:

```
<div id="my-video-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="my-video-container" style="display:none;">
```

For same reason change the code for the play button (you can remove imageID at all):

```
<a class="video-play-button" href="#"></a>
```

and change jquery like so:

```
  $('.video-play-button').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.feature-img').find('.my-video-container').show();
    $(this).siblings('.featimg').hide();
    $(this).hide(); 
  });
```

Comment: Great, [it works](http://yalleshleiron.com/ds/companies/apple/) , thanks for the tips, it helps me a lot.

Comment: Hello @G. I removed the autoplay on the embed code, coz the youtube is playing even if its hidden, is there a way that the video play after I click on the image? Thanks.

Comment: I think there is but this is not a WP question, but a js one and I'm not a js developer. In stackoverflow I find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443578/youtube-iframe-api-how-do-i-control-a-iframe-player-thats-already-in-the-html) question, maybe it can help you. (If not a deeper search on Google probably do).